# prevent MongoDB aggregate with $match from returning an empty Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an aggregate function like this

```js
 app.get('/feed', (req, res) => {
 TFBlog.aggregate([  
   { $sample: {size: 5} },
   { $match:  {"published": true} },
  
   ]).then((docs)=>{
   res.render('explore',{docs:docs});
 });
});
```

Now if aggregate finds a document that doesn't satisfy {published: true} it simply returns an empty array

So in many Use cases, I get 4 or 3 documents in return array **instead of 5**

I want this function to always **return 5 random documents** with $match criteria no matter what!!

How can I achieve this please explain?

Comment: In your case match condition should pass. *it simply returns an empty array* is wrong. Can you show us the sample documents with necessary fields and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `$match` condition to the top ?

```
db.collection.aggregate([  
   { $match:  {"published": true} },
   { $sample: {size: 5} }
])
```

Comment: good God it worked!! thanks man I ignored the staging order !!